# xpath to extract data from div and tables

Tags: html, xpath

I want to extract data for "Top 20 Most Active Value" as such

```
PTT
12,669,787.20
568.00
-6.00
-1.05
CPALL
3,696,088.88
84.00
+0.75
+0.90
```

I just list out 2 of the 20 items I want.
what is the robust xpath for the data?
the url is http://www.settrade.com/C13_MarketSummary.jsp?order=Y

My xpath `xpath('//div[@class="divDetailBox"]//tr/td/text()')` gave too many unwanted data with space in between.

Comment: @GillesQuenot, I am using python 2.7

Comment: So try iterate over each `tr` with code. Then process each `td` text

Comment: can you elaborate more? I have another `xpath('//div[@class="divDetailBox"]//tr/td/a/text()')` which extract only the PTT,CPALL, but no number

Comment: Pseudo code : `for element in xpath('//div[@class="divDetailBox"]//tr); do element.xpath('.//td).text; other processing; done`

Comment: Your xpath works in chrome dev tools, but you have to transform raw list of strings in something formatted for each row

Comment: My xpath has mix the `Top 20 Most Active Volume` with some other like `Top 20 Gainers`. I only want `Top 20 Most Active Volume` in my data. I try to use contains in xpath with words `"Top 20 Most Active Volume"` but return nothing. `xpath('//div[@class="divDetailBox"]/h3[contains(.,'Active')//tr[position() >1 and not(position() > 9)]')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
'//div[@class="divDetailBox"]/div/div[@class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"]//tr/td/text()'
```

Comment: It return blank. I `xpath('//div[@class="divDetailBox" and .//h3[.="Top 20 Most Active Volume"]]//tr/td/text()')` as your answer return `alueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters` error

Comment: So remove `text()` ! And check my edited POST about utf8

Comment: Hi, it still return error if I use Thai characters in h3 tag but no data if I use english h3 tag. I have place `# -- using utf8 --` on the script as you said

Comment: Same error ? Have you searched the error on duckduckgo or other search engine ?

Comment: Thanks. if you able to get the correct answer, it must be from my site. I am using pythonanywhere, so may be that is the problem. Also, I find that teh link I given is convert to Thai. It is the same url in English, I guess the javascript control the language and by default is in Thai

Comment: If I click on the British flag, the browser render another page, dunno how to get the page in english. I never set any preferences to have Thai, ever. Even curl in terminal render in Thai

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166040/discussion-between-bkcollection-and-gilles-quenot).

Comment: Is there alternatives to avoid using the Thai characters (in case I can't find a solution for that)?